# How can I determine string value of Oracle's datatype by its code?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database

I use `DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS` procedure to identify what datatypes are used for columns in result set for my SELECT query. But unfortunately in this way I can get only a code of Oracle's datatype (`record.col_type`) - 1, 8, 12 etc.

So I wonder, how can I easely get a string equivalent of returned datatype's code (i.e. VARCHAR2, LONG, DATE etc.) instead of its numeric code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a slightly clunky solution, but you can use a CASE statement to "lookup" the datatype descriptions.

```
case record.col_type
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_DATE then 'DATE'             
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_NUMBER then 'NUMBER'           
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_RAW then 'RAW'              
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_CHAR then 'CHAR'             
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 then 'VARCHAR2'         
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_VARCHAR then 'VARCHAR'          
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_MLSLABEL then 'MLSLABEL'         
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_BLOB then 'BLOB'             
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_BFILE then 'BFILE'            
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_CLOB then 'CLOB'              
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_CFILE then 'CFILE'            
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP then 'TIMESTAMP'        
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_TZ then 'TIMESTAMP_TZ'     
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_LTZ then 'TIMESTAMP_LTZ'    
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_YM then 'INTERVAL_YM'      
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_INTERVAL_DS then 'INTERVAL_DS'      
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_REF then 'REF'              
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_OBJECT then 'OBJECT'           
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_VARRAY then 'VARRAY'                       
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_TABLE then 'TABLE'                        
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_NAMEDCOLLECTION then 'NAMEDCOLLECTION'  
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_OPAQUE then 'OPAQUE'                            
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_NCHAR then 'NCHAR'            
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_NVARCHAR2 then 'NVARCHAR2'       
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_NCLOB then 'NCLOB'                  
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_BFLOAT then 'BFLOAT'           
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_BDOUBLE then 'BDOUBLE'          
  when dbms_types.TYPECODE_UROWID then 'UROWID'              
end case
```

To get the values for this you should query the data dictionary [as tbone suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12040908/146325).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this solution together with @tbone 's advice: 
`case record.col_type
        when  DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR  then  'VARCHAR2_TYPE' 
        when  DBMS_TYPES.NUMBER then  'NUMBER_TYPE' `
 and so on.

Comment: Some integer values are not in the list like 180 for `TIMESTAMP` and 183 for `INTERVAL_DS`. It looks like some types have multiple ids. Found it after doing some tests. Not able to find any doc about it. Oracle version is 12.2.

Comment: But `sys.col$` gives us another set of ids that we may union with the ones in `DBMS_TYPE` to get more types. `select count(*) from col$;` = 115462. `select count(distinct type#) nvals from col$;` = 24. `select listagg(col_type, ', ') within group (order by col_type) col_types from (select distinct type# col_type from col$);`= 1, 2, 8, 12, 23, 24, 25, 29, 58, 69, 96, 100, 101, 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 180, 181, 183, 208, 231.

Answer (score 9):

Look in DBMS_TYPES package (from my 11gr2):

```
select text from all_source
where owner='SYS'
and name='DBMS_TYPES'
and type='PACKAGE';

PACKAGE dbms_types AS

  TYPECODE_DATE            PLS_INTEGER :=  12;

  TYPECODE_NUMBER          PLS_INTEGER :=   2;

  TYPECODE_RAW             PLS_INTEGER :=  95;

  TYPECODE_CHAR            PLS_INTEGER :=  96;

  TYPECODE_VARCHAR2        PLS_INTEGER :=   9;

  TYPECODE_VARCHAR         PLS_INTEGER :=   1;

  TYPECODE_MLSLABEL        PLS_INTEGER := 105;

  TYPECODE_BLOB            PLS_INTEGER := 113;

  TYPECODE_BFILE           PLS_INTEGER := 114;

  TYPECODE_CLOB            PLS_INTEGER := 112;

  TYPECODE_CFILE           PLS_INTEGER := 115;

  TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP       PLS_INTEGER := 187;

  TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_TZ    PLS_INTEGER := 188;

  TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_LTZ   PLS_INTEGER := 232;

  TYPECODE_INTERVAL_YM     PLS_INTEGER := 189;

  TYPECODE_INTERVAL_DS     PLS_INTEGER := 190;



  TYPECODE_REF             PLS_INTEGER := 110;

  TYPECODE_OBJECT          PLS_INTEGER := 108;

  TYPECODE_VARRAY          PLS_INTEGER := 247;            /* COLLECTION TYPE */

  TYPECODE_TABLE           PLS_INTEGER := 248;            /* COLLECTION TYPE */

  TYPECODE_NAMEDCOLLECTION PLS_INTEGER := 122;

  TYPECODE_OPAQUE          PLS_INTEGER := 58;                 /* OPAQUE TYPE */



  /* NOTE: These typecodes are for use in AnyData api only and are short forms

     for the corresponding char typecodes with a charset form of SQLCS_NCHAR.

  */

  TYPECODE_NCHAR           PLS_INTEGER := 286;

  TYPECODE_NVARCHAR2       PLS_INTEGER := 287;

  TYPECODE_NCLOB           PLS_INTEGER := 288;



  /* Typecodes for Binary Float, Binary Double and Urowid. */

  TYPECODE_BFLOAT          PLS_INTEGER := 100;

  TYPECODE_BDOUBLE         PLS_INTEGER := 101;

  TYPECODE_UROWID          PLS_INTEGER := 104;



  SUCCESS                  PLS_INTEGER := 0;

  NO_DATA                  PLS_INTEGER := 100;
```

Also note that 109 is a user-defined type, you may need to use DESCRIBE_COLUMNS3 instead.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why some of these differs from what's in the manual?
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr06002.htm#SQLQR959
And, also, from what's in the view SYS.DBA_TAB_COLS_V$
Strange....

Comment: Query to get all column type codes from SYS package source code:
```select
    regexp_substr(text, '^.*PLS_INTEGER :=\s*(\d+);.*$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS type_code,
    regexp_substr(text, '^.*TYPECODE_([^ ]+).*$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS type_name
from all_source
where owner='SYS' and name='DBMS_TYPES' and type='PACKAGE'
and text like '%TYPECODE_%:=%;%'
order by to_number(type_code)```

Answer (score 7):

Use `ANYDATA.GetTypeName`

Here's a link with some explanation and an example: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=218

And I quote:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_anydata  ANYDATA := ANYDATA.ConvertVarchar2('String');
  3     v_typename VARCHAR2(128);
  4  BEGIN
  5     v_typename := v_anydata.GetTypeName();
  6     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Type of ANYDATA instance is [' || v_typename || ']');
  7  END;
  8  /

Type of ANYDATA instance is [SYS.VARCHAR2]

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here are [some examples of using this in a select](http://mahmoudoracle.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/anydata-in-oracle-database.html).

Comment: The solution looks very interesting but can you please explain, how can I set a type name for ANYDATA variable for each column of some SQL query? I.e. I need to create a procedure with SQL query as input parameter and collection of string datatype names for each column of this query as output parameter. Is it possible to implement with help of ANYDATA?

Comment: Check out the link I added of query-based examples.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's very informative. I'll try such solution with ANYDATA.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select 
   distinct
   c.type# type_code,
   decode(c.type#, 1, decode(c.charsetform, 2, 'NVARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR2'),
                   2, decode(c.scale, null, decode(c.precision#, null, 'NUMBER', 'FLOAT'), 'NUMBER'),
                   8, 'LONG',
                   9, decode(c.charsetform, 2, 'NCHAR VARYING', 'VARCHAR'),
                   12, 'DATE',
                   23, 'RAW', 24, 'LONG RAW',
                   69, 'ROWID',
                   96, decode(c.charsetform, 2, 'NCHAR', 'CHAR'),
                   100, 'BINARY_FLOAT',
                   101, 'BINARY_DOUBLE',
                   105, 'MLSLABEL',
                   106, 'MLSLABEL',
                   111, 'REF',
                   112, decode(c.charsetform, 2, 'NCLOB', 'CLOB'),
                   113, 'BLOB', 114, 'BFILE', 115, 'CFILE',
                   121, 'USER_TYPE',
                   122, 'USER_TYPE',
                   123, 'USER_TYPE',
                   178, 'TIME(' ||c.scale|| ')',
                   179, 'TIME(' ||c.scale|| ')' || ' WITH TIME ZONE',
                   180, 'TIMESTAMP(' ||c.scale|| ')',
                   181, 'TIMESTAMP(' ||c.scale|| ')'||' WITH TIME ZONE',
                   231, 'TIMESTAMP(' ||c.scale|| ')'||' WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE',
                   182, 'INTERVAL YEAR(' ||c.precision#||') TO MONTH',
                   183, 'INTERVAL DAY(' ||c.precision#||') TO SECOND(' ||
                         c.scale || ')',
                   208, 'UROWID',
                   'UNDEFINED') type_name from sys.col$ c order by c.type#;
```